# Ubuntu focal fossa and Sony A7RII usb tethering

Tags: usb, 20.04, camera, gphoto2

I cannot connect my Sony A7RII camera except for file transfer; `lsusb` shows not output related to the camera.

The latest `gphoto2` is installed and `gphoto2 --list-cameras| grep -i "A7R II"` claims that the camera is supported (libgphoto2 web page boldly states "Image Capture, Trigger Capture, Liveview, Configuration" abilities).

The [remote docs](http://www.gphoto.org/doc/remote/) warn *use libgphoto2 2.5.13 or newer* (which I've already checked).

Following is the output of `env LANG=C gphoto2 --debug --debug-logfile=my-logfile.txt --config` is

```
*** Error ***              
Could not detect any camera
*** Error (-105: 'Unknown model') ***
```

```
0.000002 main                        (2): ALWAYS INCLUDE THE FOLLOWING LINES WHEN SENDING DEBUG MESSAGES TO THE MAILING LIST:
0.000033 main                        (2): gphoto2 2.5.23
0.000058 main                        (2): gphoto2 has been compiled with the following options:
0.000060 main                        (2):  + gcc (C compiler used)
0.000061 main                        (2):  + popt (mandatory, for handling command-line parameters)
0.000063 main                        (2):  + exif (for displaying EXIF information)
0.000065 main                        (2):  + cdk (for accessing configuration options)
0.000066 main                        (2):  + aa (for displaying live previews)
0.000068 main                        (2):  + jpeg (for displaying live previews in JPEG format)
0.000089 main                        (2):  + readline (for easy navigation in the shell)
0.000093 main                        (2): libgphoto2 2.5.24
0.000112 main                        (2): libgphoto2 has been compiled with the following options:
0.000115 main                        (2):  + standard camlib set SKIPPING SOME (ax203 canon digigr8 dimagev directory jl2005a jl2005c kodak_dc240 mars pentax ptp2 ricoh_g3 sierra sonix sq905 st2205 topfield tp6801 SKIPPING lumix)
0.000116 main                        (2):  + gcc (C compiler used)
0.000118 main                        (2):  + ltdl (for portable loading of camlibs)
0.000120 main                        (2):  + EXIF (for special handling of EXIF files)
0.000122 main                        (2): libgphoto2_port 0.12.0
0.000124 main                        (2): libgphoto2_port has been compiled with the following options:
0.000126 main                        (2):  + iolibs: disk ptpip serial usb1 usbdiskdirect usbscsi
0.000128 main                        (2):  + gcc (C compiler used)
0.000129 main                        (2):  + ltdl (for portable loading of iolibs)
0.000131 main                        (2):  + EXIF (for vusb)
0.000133 main                        (2):  + USB (libusb1, for USB cameras)
0.000134 main                        (2):  + serial (for serial cameras)
0.000136 main                        (2):  + no resmgr (serial port access and locking)
0.000137 main                        (2):  + no ttylock (serial port locking)
0.000139 main                        (2):  + no lockdev (serial port locking)
0.000141 main                        (2): CAMLIBS env var not set, using compile-time default instead
0.000143 main                        (2): IOLIBS env var not set, using compile-time default instead
0.000144 main                        (2): invoked with following arguments:
0.000146 main                        (2):   --debug
0.000148 main                        (2):   --debug-logfile=my-logfile.txt
0.000149 main                        (2):   --config
0.000171 load_settings               (2): Creating gphoto config directory ('/home/lrkwz/.gphoto')
0.000204 load_settings               (2): Loading settings from file '/home/lrkwz/.gphoto/settings'.
0.000258 main                        (2): The user has not specified both a model and a port. Try to figure them out.
(...)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end it was caused by cabling: the USB cable I was using was a charge-only cable.

You must be sure that the cable [connects all of the four pins](https://www.dignited.com/50330/usb-data-cable-vs-usb-charging-cable/)